# Powering SD breakout board with 3.7V battery

Tags: sd-card, battery

So in a previous post I asked if I could charge an [SD card breakout board](https://www.adafruit.com/product/254) with a [3.7V LiPo battery](https://www.adafruit.com/product/1578), and I got a positive response, so I did it.

The problem is that it seems not to be enough, since, with the exact same wiring, if I supply it with my Arduino Uno, it works perfectly, but when I change the supply to the battery it gives an error. The following text is the result of an Arduino example script:

When connected with the Arduino:

```
Initializing SD card...Wiring is correct and a card is present.

Card type: SDHC

Volume type is FAT32

Volume size (bytes): 2696937472
Volume size (Kbytes): 2633728
Volume size (Mbytes): 2572

Files found on the card (name, date and size in bytes): 
SYSTEM~1/     2017-04-27 15:20:04
  WPSETT~1.DAT  2017-04-27 15:20:04 12
  INDEXE~1      2017-04-27 15:20:14 76
TEST0.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 49050
TEST1.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 60231
TEST2.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 1044
TEST3.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 34831
TEST4.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 189736
TEST5.TXT     2000-01-01 01:00:00 12419
```

When connected to the battery:

```
Initializing SD card...initialization failed. Things to check:
* is a card inserted?
* is your wiring correct?
* did you change the chipSelect pin to match your shield or module?
```

or

```
Initializing SD card...Wiring is correct and a card is present.

Card type: SD1
Could not find FAT16/FAT32 partition.
Make sure you've formatted the card
```

I've tried to supply the breakout board both through the 3V and 5V input. Can anyone notice what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you connect the ground of the SD card board to the ground of the Arduino?

Comment: no, i was connectiong to the ground of the battery, should it be the arduino's one?

Comment: Yes, all connected devices must share the same ground, otherwise they can't talk to each other.

Comment: Makes sense, so i don't connect the battery ground to anything?

Comment: Yes, you connect the battery ground to ground. There is only one ground. All "ground" points must be connected together.

Comment: Ahh, so in my breadboard i will put the arduino's ground and  the battery ground in series and from there i pull a cable to the breadboard's ground, correct?

Comment: It doesn't (much) matter how you connect all the grounds together, as long as they are all connected.

Comment: ahh great that was it, thank you, and sorry for the lack of knowledge in electronics.

Comment: Don't be sorry. You learned something today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't connected the grounds together in your circuit. You need to connect all the grounds together so every connection has a return path back to where it came from.  That means connect together:

- An Ardino GND pin
- The GND pin of the SD card breakout board
- The negative (or ground) pin of the battery